# Debugging Javascript in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to debug an issue that I'm only having in IE8.  It works fine in IE 9+, and chrome.  I'm using `Aspera` to select a file, and am calling a custom function on a callback.  the function is as follows;

```
function uploadPathsRecieved(pathsArray) {
   var file_path_selector = '#file_path';
   ...
   $(file_path_selector).text(''); // (*)
   ...
}
```

On the (*) line, I get an error that `file_path_selector` is undefined.  This didn't make much sense to me, so after some playing around to get a feel for the problem, I wound up with the following code:

```
function uploadPathsRecieved(pathsArray) {
  var x = 3;
  var y = 4;
  var z = x + y;
  z += 2;
  $('#file_path').text(''); // (*)
  ...
}
```

When I run the program with this code, I *still* get the error `"file_path_selector is undefined"` at the (*) line.  I'm out of ideas on what the next steps I should take to try and hunt down this problem are.

My gut feeling tells me that there's something being cached, but if I move the (*) line around, the error follows it, and the script window reflects the changes that I make to it.

Here's the Aspera code that's calling my function:

```
function wrapCallbacks(callbacks) {
    return wrapCallback(function() {
      var args, i;
      try {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        for ( i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          if (isObjectAndNotNull(args[i]) && isDefined(args[i].error)) {
            // error found
            if (isDefined(callbacks.error)) {
              callbacks.error.apply(null, args);
            }
            return;
          }
        }

        // success
        if (isDefined(callbacks.success)) {
          callbacks.success.apply(null, args);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        AW.utils.console.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
        AW.utils.console.trace();
      }
    });
  }
```

And here's the entirety of my function, as it exists right now:

```
var uploadPathsRecieved = function uploadPathsRecieved(pathsArray) {
    //var file_path_selector = '#file_path';
    var x = 3;
    var y = 4;
    var z = x + y;
    z += 2;
    $('#file_path').text('');

    var button_selector = '#select_aspera_file';
    var textbox_selector = '.aspera_textbox';
    /*if (uploadPathsRecieved.fileSelecting == 'cc_file') {
        file_path_selector = '#cc_file_path';
        button_selector = '#select_cc_file';
        textbox_selector = '.cc_aspera_textbox';
    } else if (uploadPathsRecieved.fileSelecting == 'preview_file') {
        file_path_selector = '#preview_file_path';
        button_selector = '#select_preview_file';
        textbox_selector = '.preview_aspera_textbox';
    }*/

    App.AsperaUploadPaths = [];
    if (pathsArray.length == 1) {
        $(button_selector).text("Clear File");
        App.AsperaUploadPaths = pathsArray;
        var error_message = pathsArray[0];
        $(button_selector).parent().children(textbox_selector).text(error_message).removeClass('error');
        //$(file_path_selector).attr('value', pathsArray[0]);
    }
    else 
    {
        var error_message = 'Please select a single file';
        $(button_selector).parent().children(textbox_selector).text(error_message).addClass('error');
    }
}
```

Comment: use ie8 dev tools to clear the cahce and try again. without that var in ex#2, it makes no sense for that warning to appear.

Comment: I hit the "Clear Browser Cache... (CTRL + R)" button (second from the left in the developer console), refreshed, and I'm still getting the same error message in example 2. :( There's a try...catch around the callback function, and the error returned is:   message - "'file_path_selector' is undefined".  name - TypeError.  number - -2146823279

Comment: post the whole code to a fiddle or here; there's not enough present to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how much is relevant, or what is relevant.  I've added the entire function that's being called, and the entire function that's calling it.  The caller is a third party library that is calling a list of callback functions that were defined elsewhere.  This is the only callback function in that list (afaik).  The error is being caught by the try...catch in the caller function.

Comment: Debugging IE8, I feel bad for you, son. I got 99 problems but IE ain't one...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  file_path was an `<input>`, and IE 8 and below doesn't allow you to add text or html to inputs.
I fixed it by changing `$(file_path_selector).text('');` to `$(file_path_selector).attr('value', '');`